# Flink JobManager disconnected to taskmanager

Tags: akka, apache-flink

I use Flink cluster(Standalone) and it disconnects task manager from Job manager after few hours.

I follows basic step of setup standalone cluster in flink.apache.org and I use 1 master node and 2 workers and they are Mac osx.
only 1 worker is disconnected from jobManager.

I share log file and please give me solution.

below is Job Manager's Log

```
2017-01-28 16:58:32,092 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Starting JobManager (Version: 1.1.4, Rev:8fb0fc8, Date:19.12.2016 @ 10:42:50 UTC)
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Current user: macmini
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.121-b13
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Maximum heap size: 491 MiBytes
2017-01-28 16:58:32,195 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  JAVA_HOME: (not set)
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Hadoop version: 2.7.2
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  JVM Options:
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xms512m
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xmx512m
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog.file=/server/flink-1.1.4/log/flink-macmini-jobmanager-0-macmini.local.log
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/server/flink-1.1.4/conf/log4j.properties
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/server/flink-1.1.4/conf/logback.xml
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Program Arguments:
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     --configDir
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     /server/flink-1.1.4/conf
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     --executionMode
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     cluster
2017-01-28 16:58:32,198 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  Classpath: /server/flink-1.1.4/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.1.4.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.1.4.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:::
2017-01-28 16:58:32,199 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-28 16:58:32,199 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-01-28 16:58:32,354 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Loading configuration from /server/flink-1.1.4/conf
2017-01-28 16:58:32,367 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, 192.168.0.15
2017-01-28 16:58:32,367 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 512
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 8
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 2
2017-01-28 16:58:32,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-01-28 16:58:32,372 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager without high-availability
2017-01-28 16:58:32,380 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager on 192.168.0.15:6123 with execution mode CLUSTER
2017-01-28 16:58:32,416 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Security is not enabled. Starting non-authenticated JobManager.
2017-01-28 16:58:32,467 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager
2017-01-28 16:58:32,468 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager actor system at 192.168.0.15:6123
2017-01-28 16:58:32,774 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2017-01-28 16:58:32,814 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Starting remoting
2017-01-28 16:58:32,999 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123]
2017-01-28 16:58:33,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager web frontend
2017-01-28 16:58:33,020 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of JobManager log file: /server/flink-1.1.4/log/flink-macmini-jobmanager-0-macmini.local.log
2017-01-28 16:58:33,020 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Determined location of JobManager stdout file: /server/flink-1.1.4/log/flink-macmini-jobmanager-0-macmini.local.out
2017-01-28 16:58:33,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebRuntimeMonitor         - Using directory /var/folders/8m/qw1dq5sx68d38w7xg2pqhnz80000gn/T/flink-web-e2793d07-860b-4854-8c16-5805320cbd62 for the web interface files
2017-01-28 16:58:33,089 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebRuntimeMonitor         - Using directory /var/folders/8m/qw1dq5sx68d38w7xg2pqhnz80000gn/T/flink-web-upload-b98128d7-8572-47e8-bdfb-b30d287d0868 for web frontend JAR file uploads
2017-01-28 16:58:33,371 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebRuntimeMonitor         - Web frontend listening at 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081
2017-01-28 16:58:33,371 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager actor
2017-01-28 16:58:33,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Created BLOB server storage directory /var/folders/8m/qw1dq5sx68d38w7xg2pqhnz80000gn/T/blobStore-1b966770-440f-45e0-97cc-018357bdefb1
2017-01-28 16:58:33,384 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:52505 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000
2017-01-28 16:58:33,399 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.savepoint.SavepointStoreFactory  - Using job manager savepoint state backend.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,406 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistry               - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,417 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist           - Started memory archivist akka://flink/user/archive
2017-01-28 16:58:33,424 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Starting JobManager at akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,434 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebRuntimeMonitor         - Starting with JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager on port 8081
2017-01-28 16:58:33,435 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.JobManagerRetriever       - New leader reachable under akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager:null.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,448 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.standalone.StandaloneResourceManager  - Trying to associate with JobManager leader akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager
2017-01-28 16:58:33,532 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager was granted leadership with leader session ID None.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,549 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.standalone.StandaloneResourceManager  - Resource Manager associating with leading JobManager Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager#-320621701] - leader session null
2017-01-28 16:58:34,996 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.standalone.StandaloneResourceManager  - TaskManager ResourceID{resourceId='6817357d50e00e3879507d8a0ecd9f42'} has started.
2017-01-28 16:58:34,998 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at 192.168.0.17 (akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.17:49684/user/taskmanager) as 0495d83fc1767f41770ba9feb3c7b8a6. Current number of registered hosts is 1. Current number of alive task slots is 8.
2017-01-28 16:58:37,464 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.standalone.StandaloneResourceManager  - TaskManager ResourceID{resourceId='31c1ebbfdbd41ae798718575aff2fb8c'} has started.
2017-01-28 16:58:37,465 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Registered TaskManager at 192.168.0.16 (akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.16:50620/user/taskmanager) as 794bb699ab58aa3eab324924a8b8409e. Current number of registered hosts is 2. Current number of alive task slots is 16.
2017-01-28 17:05:04,426 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Created BLOB cache storage directory /var/folders/8m/qw1dq5sx68d38w7xg2pqhnz80000gn/T/blobStore-8d18ed4c-6a33-4d62-a63b-0aa2a82569eb
2017-01-28 17:05:04,464 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Downloading 8b816b83aa254a2853a32e51b37ee1b3c14ef82a from localhost/127.0.0.1:52505
2017-01-28 17:07:45,153 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Downloading 8808acee6a1b7c225a9b471a1429a75ec75d4c16 from localhost/127.0.0.1:52505
2017-01-29 09:54:01,082 WARN  akka.remote.RemoteWatcher                                     - Detected unreachable: [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.17:49684]
2017-01-29 09:54:01,089 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Task manager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.17:49684/user/taskmanager terminated.
2017-01-29 09:54:01,090 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceManager             - Unregistered task manager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.17:49684/user/taskmanager. Number of registered task managers 1. Number of available slots 8.
```

TaskManager's log

```
2017-01-28 16:58:33,162 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Starting TaskManager (Version: 1.1.4, Rev:8fb0fc8, Date:19.12.2016 @ 10:42:50 UTC)
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Current user: macmini3
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.121-b13
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Maximum heap size: 1024 MiBytes
2017-01-28 16:58:33,268 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JAVA_HOME: (not set)
2017-01-28 16:58:33,271 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Hadoop version: 2.7.2
2017-01-28 16:58:33,271 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM Options:
2017-01-28 16:58:33,271 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:+UseG1GC
2017-01-28 16:58:33,271 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xms1024M
2017-01-28 16:58:33,271 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xmx1024M
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog.file=/server/flink-1.1.4/log/flink-macmini3-taskmanager-0-macmini3.local.log
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/server/flink-1.1.4/conf/log4j.properties
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/server/flink-1.1.4/conf/logback.xml
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Program Arguments:
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     --configDir
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     /server/flink-1.1.4/conf
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Classpath: /server/flink-1.1.4/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.1.4.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.1.4.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/server/flink-1.1.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:::
2017-01-28 16:58:33,272 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-28 16:58:33,273 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-01-28 16:58:33,277 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Maximum number of open file descriptors is 10240
2017-01-28 16:58:33,295 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Loading configuration from /server/flink-1.1.4/conf
2017-01-28 16:58:33,305 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, 192.168.0.15
2017-01-28 16:58:33,305 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-01-28 16:58:33,305 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 512
2017-01-28 16:58:33,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2017-01-28 16:58:33,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 8
2017-01-28 16:58:33,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-01-28 16:58:33,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 2
2017-01-28 16:58:33,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-01-28 16:58:33,342 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Security is not enabled. Starting non-authenticated TaskManager.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - Trying to select the network interface and address to use by connecting to the leading JobManager.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,369 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - TaskManager will try to connect for 10000 milliseconds before falling back to heuristics
2017-01-28 16:58:33,371 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                  - Retrieved new target address /192.168.0.15:6123.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,405 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager will use hostname/address '192.168.0.17' (192.168.0.17) for communication.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,406 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager
2017-01-28 16:58:33,406 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor system at 192.168.0.17:0
2017-01-28 16:58:33,745 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2017-01-28 16:58:33,813 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Starting remoting
2017-01-28 16:58:33,963 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.17:49684]
2017-01-28 16:58:33,969 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor
2017-01-28 16:58:33,971 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.instance.InstanceConnectionInfo      - No hostname could be resolved for the IP address 192.168.0.17, using IP address as host name. Local input split assignment (such as for HDFS files) may be impacted.
2017-01-28 16:58:33,976 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConfig         - NettyConfig [server address: /192.168.0.17, server port: 49685, memory segment size (bytes): 32768, transport type: NIO, number of server threads: 8 (manual), number of client threads: 8 (manual), server connect backlog: 0 (use Netty's default), client connect timeout (sec): 120, send/receive buffer size (bytes): 0 (use Netty's default)]
2017-01-28 16:58:33,977 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Messages between TaskManager and JobManager have a max timeout of 10000 milliseconds
2017-01-28 16:58:33,980 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Temporary file directory '/var/folders/9n/3xqj9xzx67sd5dx1z59506840000gn/T': total 118 GB, usable 105 GB (88.98% usable)
2017-01-28 16:58:34,041 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool  - Allocated 64 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 2048, bytes per segment: 32768).
2017-01-28 16:58:34,080 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Limiting managed memory to 0.7 of the currently free heap space (669 MB), memory will be allocated lazily.
2017-01-28 16:58:34,090 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.iomanager.IOManager          - I/O manager uses directory /var/folders/9n/3xqj9xzx67sd5dx1z59506840000gn/T/flink-io-8fe2058a-8e2b-4fa6-8c5c-7e1a5edd8993 for spill files.
2017-01-28 16:58:34,103 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                  - User file cache uses directory /var/folders/9n/3xqj9xzx67sd5dx1z59506840000gn/T/flink-dist-cache-a663c4dc-6c17-43ba-af73-6d798b0f5196
2017-01-28 16:58:34,294 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor at akka://flink/user/taskmanager#-1292864950.
2017-01-28 16:58:34,295 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager data connection information: 192.168.0.17 (dataPort=49685)
2017-01-28 16:58:34,296 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager has 8 task slot(s).
2017-01-28 16:58:34,298 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Memory usage stats: [HEAP: 79/1024/1024 MB, NON HEAP: 32/33/-1 MB (used/committed/max)]
2017-01-28 16:58:34,304 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 1, timeout: 500 milliseconds)
2017-01-28 16:58:34,825 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 2, timeout: 1000 milliseconds)
2017-01-28 16:58:35,077 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Successful registration at JobManager (akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager), starting network stack and library cache.
2017-01-28 16:58:35,248 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient         - Successful initialization (took 40 ms).
2017-01-28 16:58:35,285 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer         - Successful initialization (took 37 ms). Listening on SocketAddress /192.168.0.17:49685.
2017-01-28 16:58:35,286 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Determined BLOB server address to be /192.168.0.15:52505. Starting BLOB cache.
2017-01-28 16:58:35,289 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Created BLOB cache storage directory /var/folders/9n/3xqj9xzx67sd5dx1z59506840000gn/T/blobStore-941b8481-5f25-4baf-9739-1ff7f28f9262
2017-01-28 16:58:35,298 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistry               - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2017-01-29 09:54:01,399 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
2017-01-29 09:54:04,625 WARN  akka.remote.RemoteWatcher                                     - Detected unreachable: [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123]
2017-01-29 09:54:04,631 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager akka://flink/user/taskmanager disconnects from JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager: JobManager is no longer reachable
2017-01-29 09:54:04,631 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Disassociating from JobManager
2017-01-29 09:54:04,633 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Shutting down BlobCache
2017-01-29 09:54:04,642 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient         - Successful shutdown (took 2 ms).
2017-01-29 09:54:04,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer         - Successful shutdown (took 2 ms).
2017-01-29 09:54:04,651 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 1, timeout: 500 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:05,163 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 2, timeout: 1000 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:06,183 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 3, timeout: 2000 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:06,316 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Quarantined address [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.
2017-01-29 09:54:08,202 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 4, timeout: 4000 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:10,295 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Quarantined address [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.
2017-01-29 09:54:12,222 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 5, timeout: 8000 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:14,461 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Quarantined address [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.
2017-01-29 09:54:20,242 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 6, timeout: 16000 milliseconds)
2017-01-29 09:54:20,438 INFO  Remoting                                                      - Quarantined address [akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.
2017-01-29 09:54:36,263 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@192.168.0.15:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 7, timeout: 30 seconds)
```